# Strange brackets?

Tags: ios, core-data, kvc

Please anybody now how to remove strange brackets?

[image: strange brackets]

```
Tasting *tasting = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.creationDate.text = [[tasting valueForKey:@"creationDate"] description];
cell.wineName.text = [[[tasting wine]valueForKey:@"wineName"]description];
```

Comment: We desire context!!  How do you expect us to have any idea what is inside your arbitrary class?

Comment: Show us your Source JSON Data (using which you are filling your Table).

Comment: Please post the output from: `NSLog(@"wineName=%@", NSStringFromClass([[[tasting wine]valueForKey:@"wineName"] class]));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the object stored as `wineName` is an `NSSet`, which explains why you are getting the value in the form `{( "name" )}` when calling the `description` method.  Exactly *why* it's an `NSSet` object is unknown to me, given a wine a generally marketed under just one name...

To get it in your preferred format don't use `description`, and instead pull the value out and display like this:

```
NSSet *wines = [[tasting wine] valueForKey:@"wineName"];
cell.wineName.text = [wines anyObject];
```

You will also want to do something similar with the date column, using an `NSDateFormatter` object to format it to the user's preferred format.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `wineName` here is an `NSSet` (you can tell that by the `{(...)}` from the object description and of course by the log of the `class`) containing your string.
Assuming that your Set will always contain just one object, you could get it like this:

```
cell.wineName.text = [[[tasting wine] valueForKey:@"wineName"] anyObject];
```

Though, I do not think that an `NSSet` is the best option to hold some object's name...

Finally, as a sidenote... using `description` for presenting data to the user is a bad choice (the method's intended use is for debugging purposes)